# Java cannot cast HashMapNode

Tags: java, exception, casting, hashmap

I have tried something like this to get an HashMap<String, String> from an HashMap<String, Object> (containing only Strings)

(getObjects() returns this `HashMap<String, Object>`)

```
public <V> Map<String, V> castObjects(final Class<V> cast) {
    return getObjects().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> cast.isInstance(entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, cast::cast));
}

HashMap<String, String> strings = (HashMap<String, String>) castObjects(String.class)
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.HashMap$Node to java.lang.String
```

Do you guys have any idea where my castObjects method is wrong ?

Comment: You're streaming an Entry's, you filter the object, but the second argument of toMap needs to return the value of your Entry. Right now you're trying to cast the entry, no the value.

Comment: I tried to change the cast::cast to entry -> cast.cast(entry.getValue())

But still the same error

Comment: I don't see how it can be the same error, before you were casting the entry, now you would be specifically casting the object. You'll need to make a complete compilable example to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second argument to toMap needs to extract the value and cast.

```
entry -> cast.cast( entry.getValue())
```

Right now you're trying to cast the entry hence you get the error.

When I tried I didn't get an exception.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Map<String, Object> org = new HashMap<>();
    org.put("one", "two");
    
    org.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> String.class.isInstance(entry.getValue()))
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                entry -> String.class.cast(entry.getValue())
                ));
}
```

Comment: @RqndomHax I included an example that compiled and ran on ideone.com

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I recompiled my API after changing what you suggested, but I didn't so when I compiled my main program it was still using the old API, Thanks a lot !